# Can I protect range 2 or 3 cell at once?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LagU.png

I have try to search a way but don't quite sure keyword to search about this problem. Is there a way to named cell to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

Protections only work for a `Sheet` or for a `Range`, not for a `list of ranges`. Because of this, you cannot protect them both at once. See [Protect, hide, and edit sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656).

#### Workaround:

If you are open to using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), though, you could have a script that would protect both ranges:

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range1 = sheet.getRange("E3:F3");
var protection1 = range1.protect();
var range2 = sheet.getRange("H3");
var protection2 = range2.protect();
var protections = [protection1, protection2];
protections.forEach(protection => {
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
});
```

#### Reference:

- [Protect, hide, and edit sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656)